# Not sure how to proceed with $z$ and $i$ on the lhs -

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm not sure how to separate the $z$ and $i$ on the LHS. I know $i^2 = -1$ but I suspect there is an easier way then expanding $(z+i)$.
$$
(z+i)^4 = -16.
$$

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Solve for z: (z+i)^4 = -16

Comment: Write $\$$a^b$\$$ to generate $a^b$. Now let $a = i$ and $b = 2$. In fact, you can write $\$$i^2=-1$\$$ to generate $i^2=-1$.

Comment: Write $w=z+i$, and then solve $w^4=-16$, say by using polar form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one way would be to set
$ x = (z+i) $ and solve for $x^4 = -16$.
This equation has four solutions, namely 
$$
x_{1,2,3,4} = \pm\sqrt{2} \pm \sqrt{2}i
$$

Therefore you get four solutions for z:
$$
z_j = x_j - i, \quad j = 1,\dots,4.
$$

Comment: thank you, I updated the answer